# Live template with value in its name

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am a vivid fan of Emmett, but recently I am using some mixins in my `scss` and would love to define some live templates for it.

For now, I have a template that expands `fn` to `@include font-size($content$px)`. It's great, but I would love to use something like Emmett's `p10` returning `padding: 10px`. How can I do this with live templates? I tried naming it `fn$VAR0$` but it doesn't work.

Comment: not sure I follow you... Would you like to use a live template (emmet) abbreviation  in another live template definition? It's not possible, please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6414

Comment: No, I want to have abbreviation of `fn14` that will expand to `font-size(14px)`. Please note that `14` is a variable.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski That is definitely not possible. The only option to have Live Templates working like that (the final result) is to create separate live templates with all possible numbers in it. As side note: is it really `fn[tab]14` (expand `fn` live template and put `14` for `$content$` variable) so different to your proposed behaviour (`fn14[tab]`; except, of course, similarity to Emmet)?

Comment: I like using `fn$content$[tab]` because I can quickly type and forget about it. My current solution is similar, but - this is the worst thing - it places the carret inside the brackets, which is annoying.